# Morph between two objects along the curve (geometry nodes)

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, geometry, shape-keys

I have two objects with the same number of vertices. I need to array them along the curve but the first object has to morph into the second one evenly during the array. So each next copy will be slightly deformed to remind the shape of the last object.
I add an example from Illustrator. But it perfectly explains the point.
Any suggestions?
[image]
[image]

Comment: can u show us anything you tried or do you expect to do everything for you?

Comment: and yes, if you are asking a geometry nodes question, i would at least expect a basis GN blend file where you prepared as far as you could do it.

Comment: Hmmm, I admit I thought the question I'm asking is kinda from the basics of GN, like building an array or so. So it wouldn't need more than pointing on the specific node or two to achieve the result. But looks like it isn't that simple after all. if it comes to the project files, then sure. Added. Take a look, please.  
Two things I've managed: 1. array by the curve of only one object; 
2. Morph between two forms but without an array. And I have no idea how to combine those two.

Comment: if it would be that basic - you would have found out ourself, wouldn't you? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Great ... Thanks :) ... Just a cosmetics (I would say) ... your Divide node should be feed by math +1 on upper (or -1  on lower) socket to reach final stage of Sphere.